# diference an object, in constructor or method as argument

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Lets suppose we have 1 class, that implements Interface1 and Interface2 (called `I1` and `I2`)

so we have.

The class A that implements `I1`, and `I2`

Now lets say we have a class `B` that has 2 constructors:

```
Public B(I1 Argument);

public B(I2 Argument);
```

if we do:

```
A NewVarA = new A();
B NewVar = new B(A);
```

which constructor will be called?

in which order the type of the object will be evaluated?

Comment: Why you ask us, simply test it yourself

Comment: maybe the C# tag make you miss understood the question, i mean say generally, which behavior can we expect from this kind of code, is there any common practice or is just compiler-language dependant.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is not well defined, which is why C# compiler will fire a compilation error, he would recognize that the call as ambiguous

[Take a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pESZ.png)

I`m pretty sure most compilers would catch that, but anyway it is not a recommended practice